# Eclipse/Freemarker plugin: syntax highlighting failure

Tags: eclipse, freemarker

I have the JBoss Freemarker IDE installed in Eclipse/Indigo. For the first .ftl I created the syntax highlighting/parsing works fine. But when I copied this to  create new .flt syntax highlighting/parsing just does not happen. The  icon on the file itself suggests it has been notices by the plugin, but there seem to be no way of convincing the plugin to start working on the file. (The contents of the file itself are fine: if I paste the content to the original file the syntax highlighting works.)

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to select "Open With>Freemarker Editor". Obscure and weird behaviour, for sure.

Comment: `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` might be your friend...